# ESAPI encoding give different output on UI

Tags: java, spring-mvc, xss, esapi

I am trying to implement ESAPI encoding to prevent XSS attack in my spring-mvc project. My approach is before sending input back in response I will encode it using ESAPI.encoder(), so that in page response input attribute is encoded.

My assumption was that when I return encoded response, in my page response I will get encoded chars and in my input field I will get normal chars, but my input field is also set with encoded chars.

Below is sample code I have written in my controller before sending response.

```
model.addAttribute("input", setValue(ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTMLAttribute(getInput())));
return "reports/salaryreport";
```

I was expecting browser to automatically decode these encoded chars and show original input, whereas it always show modified/encoded value in input field.

Am I doing something wrong here, or my expectation is not correct?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: MUCH easier to answer if you provide an input/output example and what you actually expect to happen!

Comment: I have one input field in JSP, I am providing input "NZIC123 !"#$^?%", this will be passed to controller in controller i am encoding it, and then sending it back by adding it in model, on front-end in input field now I am getting "NZIC123 &#x21;&quot;&#x23;&#x24;&#x5e;&#x3f;&#x25;".
I was under impression that browser will automatically decode it and I will get "NZIC123 !"#$^?%", but looks like my assumption is wrong

Comment: This may sound like a dumb question, but what makes it to the browser?  I’ve seen this happen when a value somehow gets double-encoded.

Comment: I agree, its a dumb question & assumption, i am using ESAPI encodeHTMLAttribute encoding in controller and expecting browser to decode it automatically

Comment: So it's not a dumb question.  I just used your output on a simple HTML page, and `NZIC123 &#x21;&quot;&#x23;&#x24;&#x5e;&#x3f;&#x25;` renders correctly in chrome, firefox, Edge, and IE11.  Something in your web framework is adding an additional layer of encoding.  Grab the data value in question from your browser's developer tools, or from view->source.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the ESAPI-encoded value to some kind of web framework.

My money is that the browser is receiving the equivalent of `NZIC123 &amp;#x21;&amp;quot;&amp;#x23;&amp;#x24;&amp;#x5e;&amp;#x3f;&amp;#x25;` and that's why you're getting this behavior.

I tested `NZIC123 &#x21;&quot;&#x23;&#x24;&#x5e;&#x3f;&#x25;` on Edge, IE11, Chrome 75, and firefox.  It renders correctly in all 4 instances.

The call `model.addAttribute()` might already be offering attribute encoding, and the behavior you're getting is because it's encoding the ampersands that ESAPI is providing.